# How do I retain selections across pagination or lazy loading while fetching new data every time

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination, gmail

I am trying to load a huge dataset and hence looking for some pagination/ lazy loading.

I have following functionalities :

1. Selection.
2. Un-selection
3. Filtering by 3 different columns.

Now the issue is that I fetch new data every time on a page-click or lazy load. I do the same for filters.

Every time I receive a new data set, I wash away the previous one.

And finally I want all the selection made to be available on one `Add` button.

With this approach can it be possible to retain user selections throughout all actions. I have tried lot many approach like pushing and popping data from a temporary table and all, but some how all my use case doesn't pass.

I see Gmail is maintaining this somehow. Any idea how Gmail implements it

[A relevant question that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620897/how-does-gmail-retain-the-checkbox-selections-from-page-to-page)

Comment: As long as you maintain unique id's for rows, and not clear the table each time you get new rows in, I cannot set why this should be hard to achieve with DataTables.

Comment: Since each entry contains huge data, I want to clear the table each time I get new rows, else I would end up having quite a huge object.

Comment: What is huge? As long as rows is injected consecutively you can have many. Alternatively, If you use serverside sourcing you will need to invent a system where selected rows info is passed back to the server (in one of the callbacks) If you think about it, I do not think gmail have much data presented "live" either, for example you cannot delete "all", just a full page or those you mark on the screen.

Comment: The thing is that any kind of filtering is done on the entire dataset (server dataset) which has as much as 1 lac entries. ( I definitely do not want to have all these on UI at one point of time). As the result of filtering only the filtered result needs be shown. It is this mixing of filtered and normal results which makes thing messy